# Paginate Multiple Collections in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm trying to show twenty items in a news feed sorted by created_at date. The only problem is that these items can be from multiple modles (images, posts, member highlights, etc). I'd like the timelines to match up properly, which won't happen if I just select a couple form the most recent of each. Any suggestions for the simplest way to do this? The closest I've gotten is to use UNION ALL but would be intersted in seeing a full example. Thanks!

Comment: What about making a view (table) in the database?

Comment: I agree, sounds like a job for a view.

Comment: then maybe create another model for the view?

Comment: Consider a many to many polymorphic relationship. You create a feedable table and relate it to images, posts, member highlights, etc. http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations